# JavaScript constructor arguments

Tags: javascript, constructor, arguments

could anyone please explain to me how exactly JavaScript constructors work? Specifically I am talking about the following scenario:

In my Webside Code I have two elements, that I need to observe with a MutationObserver. I tried doing that with one Observer only, but that did not work. So I came with the following solution:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) { /*Code to do stuff */ });
var observer2 = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) { /*Code to do stuff */ });
```

Then I gave them something to observe:

```
observer.observe(document.getElementById("textarea1"), {attributs: true, attributeFilter: ['style'] });
observer2.observe(document.getElementById("textarea2"), {attributs: true, attributeFilter: ['style'] });
```

With this observers I wanted to change the style, and because else I would have gotten an endless loop, I told the observer to .disconnect(), changed the style and then let it start observe again.

Because both "textarea1" and "textarea2" were basically the same (but different content), I didn't want to have the same code twice, with the only difference being the specific observer object to call.

So I tried the following:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutate(mutations, observer);
    });
var observer2 = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutate(mutations, observer2);
    });
function mutate(mutations, observer) {
/*do stuff with mutations and observer*/
}
```

And it worked just fine.

And here's the thing I don't really get: How can I pass something as an argument to a constructor, if the result of the constructor is the argument I want to use...?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by declaring the variable before actually using it.

Example:

```
var observer, observer2, mutate;

observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutate(mutations, observer);
});

observer2 = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutate(mutations, observer2);
});

mutate = function (mutations, observer) {
    /*do stuff with mutations and observer*/
}
```

Newer versions of Javascript actually do this for you, the concept is called hoisting. That is why this works.

Answer (score 0):

All `var` declarations are hoisted, which means your code is equivalent to:

```
var observer;

observer = new ...
```

The variable name `observer` exists in the scope from the beginning.

From there all you have is this:

```
var observer;

function () {
    foo(observer);
}
```

Which is entirely legal code. You're defining a function which, when called, does something with the variable `observer` from the parent scope. The variable is only evaluated at the time of the call, so it matters what its value is *at that time*. Since it's being called *sometime after* you have assigned something to `observer`, this works just fine.

Similar illustrative example:

```
var foo;

setTimeout(function () { alert(foo); });

foo = 'bar';
```

This alerts `bar`, because *at the time the callback is executed*, `foo` holds the value `'bar'`.